# Code Signing of JAR dependency on JDK version

Tags: java, security, jar, applet, code-signing

I have a requirement in my code to remove a security warning that comes for an applet code that we use in the JSP file. Understanding that code signing the JAR file for the applet will resolve the issue, we got it done and redeployed the code. 
Now I see the issue fixed in some of the machines including mine (I have JDK 1.6). But others get either of the 2 error messages still (They have JDK 1.7 and 1.8)

Any advise would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you,
Sandesh

[image]

[image]

Comment: *"Any advise.."* Ask a question.. *"..would be greatly appreciated."* ..you're welcome. :)

Comment: What I meant to say..what am I doing wrong here that the code signed jar still behaves like an unsigned jar. Please help

Comment: *"What am I doing wrong here that the code signed jar still behaves like an unsigned jar?"* Would be the first question you've actually asked. Please [edit the question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/38359621/edit) & include it. Don't forget the '?' on the end. Sometimes I don't have enough time to read the entire question before knowing if I can answer, so skip direct to the sentence ending with a question mark.

Comment: Is the Jar self signed, or is it signed using a code signing certificate issued by a CA?

Comment: Thank you Andrew... will keep these points in mind. The JAR is not self signed  and is signed by a CA. The signed JAR file was updated and the application EAR was redeployed.

Comment: We had tried to do this the self signed way as well. We had also changed the Manifest entries but that did not help. Please let us know what we are missing and how this issue can be resolved?

Comment: *"The JAR is not self signed and is signed by a CA."* OK. Make sure to completely uninstall the app. before doing further tests with the newly signed code.

Comment: Hello Andrew, We got the popup issue resolved . There was one more applet in the code that needed code signing. Apparently we landed in another problem: the signed jar when used throws a Class Not Found Exception and does not show up in Java cache as well (the unsigned jar does show up in the Java cache an loads correctly except the regular security warning). Does code signing a jar cause this error or is there anything else that we are missing?

Comment: *Every* Jar for user use needs to be digitally signed.